# Sum the values of all rasters in a user defined list

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, raster-calculator

I am creating a QGIS plugin a part of which is like the SAGA Rasters sum tool. The user interface will have a widget to which the user will load the raster layers. I am trying to get the pixel-wise sum of values of the loaded rasters.

Like if the user loads 3 rasters R1, R2, R3 then for a pixel Pij, having values 5, 7 and 6 in R1, R2 and R3 respectively, in the new raster Pij = R1ij+R2ij+R3ij = 5+7+6 = 18

I am stuck up with both - creating the UI and the calculations.

So the first part of my question is about creating a QListWIdget and dragging and dropping the layers into the widget and using these layers for additions. The best I could get to was to add the QListWidget into the UI using QtCreator. Couldn't get to add and call layers from the QListWidget.

Here is the code I used with a push button to add layers in the QListWidget, but the layers add as a single row and I don't know how to use these for the actual calculations.

```
def add_rasters(self):
    name=QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self.dlg, 'Select Rasters', '','*.tif')
    name_str = str(name)
    list = []
    list.append(name)
    self.dlg.listWidget.insertItem(2,name_str)

self.dlg.pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.add_rasters)
```

Using the above code the ListWidget gets filled up like:
`(['C:/QGIS_plugin/rstr1.tif', 'C:/QGIS_plugin/rstr2.tif', 'C:/QGIS_plugin/rstr3.tif'], '*.tif')`

Next I am querying about the calculations:

I can do the addition calculation by manually adding up all the layers in the list; but I could not figure out a way to do the calculation automatically for n-number of the layers loaded in the widget.

Below is my code for addition of layers already loaded in the QGIS map project.

```
import processing
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry

entries = []

myList=[layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
print(my_list)

for i in range(0, len(myList)):
     raster = myList[i]
     #readRst = QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString(raster)
     ras1 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
     ras1.raster = raster
     ras1.ref = "ext_lyr" + str(i+1) +"@1"
     ras1.bandNumber = 1
     entries.append(ras1)

formula = '(' + entries[0].ref + ' + ' + entries[1].ref +  ')'

output = r"C:/QGIS_plugin/rstrs_sum.tif"
calc = QgsRasterCalculator(formula, output, 'GTiff', raster.extent(), raster.width(), raster.height(), entries)
calc.processCalculation()
```

I am afraid that I am unable to frame this question properly (mixing two questions), but I am myself not sure how this would work best. I have gone through several posts on this site and now I am completely lost!

I am quite new to python programming and QGIS, hence need help with the simplest things also. Hoping to get some help here with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Drag & Drop

It is fairly easy to implement a `QListWidget` which accepts drops from the system file explorer, or the QGIS Browser.

```
from pathlib import Path
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QListWidget

class DropList(QListWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.items = set()  # Keep a set of filepaths
        self.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.setSelectionMode(QListWidget.ExtendedSelection)

    def addItem(self, item):  # Ensure that files are only added once
        if item in self.items:
            return
        self.items.add(item)
        super().addItem(str(item))

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dragLeaveEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        mimeData = event.mimeData()

        # Drop from QGIS Browser, or from system file explorer
        if mimeData.hasUrls():
            for url in mimeData.urls():
                filepath = Path(url.toLocalFile())
                if filepath.suffix.lower() in (".tif", ".tiff"):
                    self.addItem(filepath)
```

It is a bit more complicated to handle drops from the QGIS Layer panel. You have to get the qgis-specific mimeData, and recreate a `QgsLayerTreeNode` from it. Once you got the node, check if it matches a raster layer, and add its source to your list. `dropEvent` becomes:

```
def dropEvent(self, event):
    mimeData = event.mimeData()
    # Drop from QGIS Browser, or from system file explorer
    if mimeData.hasUrls():
        for url in mimeData.urls():
            filepath = Path(url.toLocalFile())
            if filepath.suffix.lower() in (".tif", ".tiff"):
                self.addItem(filepath)

    # Drop from QGIS Layers panel
    else:
        if not mimeData.hasFormat(  "application/qgis.layertreemodeldata"):
            return
        encodedData = mimeData.data( "application/qgis.layertreemodeldata" )
        doc = QDomDocument()
        if not doc.setContent( encodedData ):
            return
        rootElem = doc.documentElement();
        if rootElem.tagName() != "layer_tree_model_data":
            return

        elem = rootElem.firstChildElement()
        while not elem.isNull():
            node = QgsLayerTreeNode.readXml( elem, QgsProject.instance() )
            if (node and QgsLayerTree.isLayer(node) and isinstance(node.layer(), QgsRasterLayer) and node.layer().source().lower().endswith(".tif")):
                self.addItem(Path(node.layer().source()))
            elem = elem.nextSiblingElement()
```

### Sum n rasters

Here is a simple function which takes a list of filepath, generates `QRasterLayers` from them, and sum them.

```
def sum_rasters(paths, outputname):

    # Compute entries from filenames
    layers =  [QgsRasterLayer(str(path)) for path in paths]
    entries = []
    for i, layer in enumerate(layers, 1):
        entry = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
        entry.ref = f"layer_{i}@1"
        entry.raster = layer
        entry.bandNumber = 1
        entries.append(entry)


    # Create operation string
    operation = "+".join(entry.ref for entry in entries)

    # Actual computation
    calc = QgsRasterCalculator(
        operation,
        outputname,
        "GTiff",
        layers[0].extent(),  # Use first layer as ref for extent & size
        layers[0].width(),
        layers[0].height(),
        entries,
    )
    return calc.processCalculation()
```

You may want to load the generated raster into your project afterward.

```
output_raster = QgsRasterLayer(outputname)
output_raster.setName("Sum")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(output_raster )
```

### Binding it together

Here is a simple dialog which uses the previously defined widgets and functions.

```
class ComputationDialog(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.dropList = DropList(self)

        # Optional Toolbar: add raster from file explorer, and remove raster from dialog
        self.toolbar = QToolBar(self)
        addFromFileAction = self.toolbar.addAction(
            QIcon(":/images/themes/default/mActionAdd.svg"),  # qgis icon
            "Add new raster"
        )
        addFromFileAction.triggered.connect(self.dropList.addFromFile)
        removeSelectedAction = self.toolbar.addAction(
            QIcon(":/images/themes/default/mActionRemove.svg"), # qgis icon
            "Remove selected raster"
        )
        removeSelectedAction.triggered.connect(self.dropList.removeSelected)
        self.toolbar.setIconSize(QSize(16,16))

        self.sumButton = QPushButton("Sum")
        self.sumButton.clicked.connect(self.onSum)

        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.dropList)
        layout.addWidget(self.sumButton)


    def onSum(self):
        sum_rasters(self.dropList.items, "C:/Temp/Output.tif")
```

In order to use the toolbar, you have to add the following method to yout `DropList` Class

```
def addFromFile(self):
    names, _ =  QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, 'Select Rasters', '','*.tif')
    for name in names:
        self.addItem(Path(name))

def removeSelected(self):
    for item in self.selectedItems():
        self.items.remove(Path(item.text()))
        self.takeItem(self.row(item))
```

Comment: This is amazing!!! Thank you so very much! I could load the layers in the widget using the addFromFile() method and do the calculations using sum_rasters(). I am still trying the drag and drop option. All this while I was trying to understand and implement this code. Hence the delay in accepting this answer. But really thanks a lot!